# MongoDB declare key by Javascript Value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to set a value as a mongodb array key.

my value for is

`var value = "arrayKey"`
and i want to update a mongodb collection and set this value as a key.

```
collection.update(
    {
        "schraenke.name": schrank.name
    }, 
    {
        $push: {
            value: {
                "test": test
            },
        }
    }
});
```

When i try it the key is value and not "arraKey".

Answer (score 2):

That's because keys are literal when written that way, you can create the object first and use bracket notation to use the dynamic key, then pass in the object, something like

```
var value = "arrayKey"
var push  = {};

push[value] = { "test": test };

collection.update({"schraenke.name": schrank.name }, {$push: push});
```